# The indentation getting error in my do statement

Tags: java, formatting

So I am having trouble with the indentation for the `do` statement. Would the indentation be different because I checked everything and it seems to be fine from looking through it?

```
public void menu()
{
    char option = '\0'; //This is intaillsing the character 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome" + customerName);
    System.out.println("\n");


    //These will be all the option that will be dispalyed for the user to choose an option 
    System.out.println("A. Check Balance");
    System.out.println("B. Deposit");
    System.out.println("C. Withdraw");
    System.out.println("D. Previous transaction");
    System.out.println("E. Deposit using checks");
    System.out.println("F. Exit");

    do //This is saying to do all of these statement 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an option");
        option = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("\n");

        switch(option)
        {
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Balance = " + balance);
        }
    }//This indentation is showing me error 
}
```

Comment: Indentation means nothing in Java. You have no `while` after your `do`

Comment: you need to use a do while loop, there is no just do

Comment: The great thing about free-form languages is --> that doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 4):

Java does not have semantically meaningful white space in loop constructs. You're missing one-half of the loop construct. Specifically the `while (condition);` of a `do-while` loop.

```
do {
   // ...
} while (condition);
```

Comment: It is not "whitespace significant".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils That's what I said, not semantically meaningful. In contrast with python (where it is).

Comment: Indeed, I'm only suggesting using common descriptors.

Comment: Nit-pick: white space is definitely significant in Java, it's just that the amount or the type of it doesn't matter. You need whitespace between identifiers or keywords and other identifiers and keywords, and sometimes to avoid confusion with run-in operators as well.  http://wiki.c2.com/?SyntacticallySignificantWhitespaceConsideredHarmful

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I deliberately added "in loop constructs".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, true, but a "whitespace significant" language is one where indentation defines code blocks and scope by design. It's important but perhaps obvious that `publicstaticvoidmain` is gobbly goo without proper whitespace.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Please read the link in my comment - it also shows why Elliot used the term "semantically meaningful white space". There are languages like Fortran where whitespace between keywords and identifiers can be omitted in some cases, the equivalent of `publicstaticvoidmain` so to speak.